# Group-like elements of universal enveloping algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, formal-groups

Suppose $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$. Take $A=U(\mathfrak g[[t]])$, a universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak g[[t]]$ over $\mathbb C[[t]]$.

Then we may define inverse maps $\exp$ and $\log$ between $tA$ and $1+tA$. Note that $\exp$ maps Lie-like elements to group-like elements.
Also, recall that group-like elements of any Hopf algebra form a group, which in this case coincides with the image of algebra of Lie-like elements under $\exp$.

The questions is, how is this group related to complex Lie groups with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, or corresponding local/formal groups, which might be more appropriate here?

Comment: Sorry if my question is naive but what is $\mathfrak g[[t]]$ and $U(\mathfrak g[[t]])$ ?

Comment: If I remember right this is all explained very nicely in Bourbaki.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou $\mathfrak g[[t]]$ is just $\mathfrak g \otimes \mathbb C[[t]]$, i.e, formal power series with coefficients in $\mathfrak g$. Since it is a Lie algebra over $\mathbb C[[t]]$, we can take its universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak g[[t]])$ over that ring. Or we can take $U(\mathfrak g)$ and tensor it with $\mathbb C[[t]]$ afterwards to obtain a Hopf algebra over that ring, these two are the same.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to take $U(\mathfrak{g})[t]$ and then complete it in the $t$-adic topology. I wonder if this is what you actually want to do. If you do that, then $\exp(tg) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \tfrac{t^n g^n}{n!}$ makes sense for any $g \in \mathfrak{g}$, and gives a group like element

Comment: I think this is more or less the same thing as the formal group of $G$. The latter is groupe-like elts in the completion of $U(\mathfrak g)$ w.r.t the augmentation ideal, which is generated by $\mathfrak g$, while the former is as David say the completion of $U(\mathfrak g)[t]$ w.r.t to the ideal generated by $t\mathfrak g$, so I'd say this is something like the Rees algebra of the completion of the enveloping algebra.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Of course, in all of what I've said I meant the $t$-adic topology to make sense of applying formal power series.

Comment: If what you meant is the $t$-adic completion of $U(\mathfrak{g})[t]$, then I am fairly sure that the answer is that the group like elements are precisely $\exp(t \mathfrak{g}[[t]])$; I'll try to work out the details. If what you meant was $U(g[[t]])$, then I don't think there are nontrivial group like elements. To be clear, if $g$ is a nonzero element of $\mathfrak{g}$, is $\sum \tfrac{t^n g^n}{n!}$ an element of your ring or not?